# Linux Command - Find words that are either 3 or 8 letters in length

Tags: regex, grep

I have a text file with many words. i need to find words of either 3 letters in length or 8 letter in length. i can find the 3 and 8 letter words separately with the below commands. how do I combine the results into one output?

```
grep -E '^.{3}$' words | wc -w

grep -E '^.{8}$' words | wc -w
```

Comment: Use an alternation of your existing patterns... `pattern1|pattern2`

Comment: Thanks Mark.ike this? grep -E '^.{3}$' words|grep -E '^.{8}$' words | wc -w  it only reads the first part and doesnt move on to the 8 letter count.

Comment: `grep -E '^.{3}$|^.{8}$' words`

Comment: @melpomene putbur comment as answer

Comment: You can also combine multiple `-e` parameters: `grep -E -e '^.{3}$' -e '^.{8}$'`

Comment: The input file contains only one word per line, right?

Comment: @melpomene thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is:

```
grep -E '^(.{3}|.{8})$'
```

And put other ways together:

```
grep -E '^.{3}$|^.{8}$'
grep -E -e '^.{3}$' -e '^.{8}$'
```

Check this: [Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

An example:

```
$ cat file
orange
banana
who
what
we
eat
buzzkill
find

$ grep -E '^(.{3}|.{8})$' file
who
eat
buzzkill

$ grep -E '^.{3}$|^.{8}$' file
who
eat
buzzkill

$ grep -E -e '^.{3}$' -e '^.{8}$' file
who
eat
buzzkill
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **count** the 3-letter and 8-letter words, use:

```
grep -Ewc '.{3}|.{8}' file
```

If you want to **see** the 3-letter and 8-letter words, use:

```
grep -Ew '.{3}|.{8}' file
```

So if your file contains:

```
a
be
sea
deee
goldfish
somethinglong
```

You will get:

```
grep -Ewc '.{3}|.{8}' file
2
```

or:

```
grep -Ew '.{3}|.{8}' file
sea
goldfish
```